# URL Rewriting Problem

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite my URL's subdomain.

http://**username**.domain.com will show content of http://www.domain.com/user.php?u=**username** but URL stay as http://**username**.domain.com . (I mean *url masking*)

(Username's can contain a-z 0-9 and hypens)
*Also if subdomain is **www** or **api**, don't redirect them*

I'm using this for my *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule .* /user.php?u=%1 [L]
```

(After @mfarver's advice) I'm trying this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* /user.php?u=%1 [L]
```

but this time getting 500 Internal Server error:

```
[Mon May 30 20:10:44 2011] [alert] [client 81.6.xx.xxx] /home/blablabla/public_html/.htaccess: AllowOverride not allowed here
```

(from error log)

My server's *httpd.conf* file's *virtualhost* settings

```
<VirtualHost 109.73.70.169:80>
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disabled
        UserDir enabled USERNAME
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule concurrent_php.c>
        php4_admin_value open_basedir "/home/USERNAME/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp"
        php5_admin_value open_basedir "/home/USERNAME/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !concurrent_php.c>
        <IfModule mod_php4.c>
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/USERNAME/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/USERNAME/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/USERNAME/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    ServerName DOMAIN.net
    ServerAlias *.DOMAIN.net
<Directory "/home/USERNAME/public_html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
    DocumentRoot /home/USERNAME/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@DOMAIN.net
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/DOMAIN.net combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/DOMAIN.net-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User USERNAME # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup USERNAME USERNAME
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup USERNAME USERNAME
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/USERNAME/public_html/cgi-bin/


    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/USERNAME/DOMAIN.net/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```

Also *.DOMAIN.net added to my DNS ZONES as **A record**.

Comment: Looks good but debugging mod_rewrite is always tricky.  I would recommend breaking it down.  Comment out all of the conditions and make sure the rule works first, then add them back one at a time.  In my experience mod_rewrite behaves slightly different in .htaccess vs in the conf files.  Also make sure that you are actually using .htaccess (ie overrides are allowed)

Comment: I'm sure server using .htaccess file. Because when i type random characters to my .htaccess file, i'm getting 500 INTERNET SERVER error. So my `.htaccess` file is working. I'm not similar with .htaccess commands very well. First i will comment out 2nd 3th and 4th lines right?

Comment: @mfarver, after your advice i'm delete conditions but this time i'm getting error. Please look **ADDITION 1** on answer. I was edited it.

Comment: Question improved totally

Comment: You probably forgot to restart `httpd` after editing `httpd.conf`

Comment: `AllowOverride not allowed here`: says what the problem is. Totally unrelated to the rewrite. That user is using a directive in .htaccess that isn't allowed (think about it, if you'd allow [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in .htacces, then it has zero use for server and vhost level and the webserver admin looses control).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a .htaccess file, your server should have AllowOverride direction for these domain contexts. Check you servers general configuration.

Also you need a redirect for thise kind of rewriting.

instead of:
    RewriteRule .* /user.php?u=%1 [L]

use:
    RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/user.php?u=%1 [r,L]

After your edit: you do not need redirecting.

Comment: After chatting over this problem on another platform I have concluded this problem is not only about rewriting. Domain names and vhost configuration are not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job - you need "PT" to stop it from being a redirect.  If it isn't a redirect the URL won't change in the browser:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule .* /user.php?u=%1 [PT,L]
```